# Woo Commerce does not display categories if I'm not logged in as Admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm making an e-commerce website with woo commerce and I have this weird issue that I cannot find a solution for.

When I log out of admin or view the page through the customizer in wordpress the categories on the home page suddenly disappear however when I log back in, they are there again.

I am using this piece of code to display the categories on the homepage.

```
    <?php


        $orderby = 'name';
        $order = 'asc';
        $hide_empty = true;
        $cat_args = array(
            'orderby'    => $orderby,
            'order'      => $order,
            'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
        );

        $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $cat_args );

        if( !empty($product_categories) ){
            foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category) {
                    $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $category->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
                    $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );

                echo '<a style="background-image: url(' . $image . ')" class="category-link" href="'.get_term_link( $category ).'" >';
                echo '<div class="layer">';
                echo '<article class="category">';
                echo '<h3>' . $category->name . '</h3>';
                echo '<span>Shop ' . $category->name . ' Now</span>';
                echo '</article>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</a>';
            }
        } ?>
```

Any help is appreciated!